# When questions are converted to communiti wiki - how should we treat existing answers?

Tags: big-list, community-wiki

If an author or moderator would change a question to *community wiki*, already existing answers would'nt be converted automatically. Should we convert also the existing answers? All, or just the top answer, or should a separate summarizing CW answer be created without touching other answers?

This question especially targets the [[big-list]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) tagged topics.

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note: what happens to the reputation received by the submitter and the repliers when a question is converted to CW?

Comment: @mindcorrosive: I _think_ that no-one loses any reputation by something becoming CW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question. My initial assumption would be that if a question is CW then it's answers should all be as well. I'd assumed that this happens automatically if the question is changed: is this not the case?

Comment: It's not the case. I've checked it on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-are-other-good-resources-on-line-for-information-about-tex-latex-and-friend - all answers remained non-wiki. I converted just my own answer to wiki manually.

Comment: Oh right: shows what I know. What is the best approach then? Should all answers be converted to CW if the question is?

Comment: I think this is a good reason to convert to CW as early as possible, so that we don't have too many answers to worry about...

Comment: I think that a CW question should only have CW answers.